# What kind of calling convention is this in x86 assembly?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, x86

I already know about calling convention in c/c++.
Unfortunately, I encountered a difficult problem while I was reversing some assembly codes.

```
........
mov edx, edi
push esi
mov ecx, edx
call func1
add esp, 4
......
```

This is my stressed code.
At first, I guessed `func1` is `__fastcall` function.
But using `__fastcall` function, `callee` cleans up stack.
`func1` doesn't clean up stack and `caller` does it.

Comment: It is standard `__thiscall`, object pointer in ecx and arguments (just one) passed on the stack.  Nothing is obviously wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant thiscall is callee-cleanup while this looks like caller cleanup. It also wouldn't explain why `edx` is assigned.

Comment: thiscall is caller cleanup, same as cdecl.  C++ also supports varargs.

Comment: @HansPassant Microsoft's documentation does not share that opinion it seems.

Comment: Please share more surrounding code, and prologue/epilogue of `func1` as well.

Comment: this is not *__thiscall* - it not use *edx* and in *__thiscall* stack clear callee, not caller - not like in __cdecl

Comment: I don't see any calling conventions listed on [x86 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) that match this assembly usage, so yes, we need to see the prolog and epilog inside of `func1()`

Comment: @RbMm: we can't be sure EDX is actually a function arg and not a missed-optimization on the way to setting ECX.   But yes, `__thiscall` is callee-cleanup according to MS's docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/thiscall?view=vs-2017, contrary to Hans' earlier comment.  So we can rule that out.  Unless the stack-popping is deferred from some earlier allocation inside this function.